# How do I remove files added as link from my project on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, csproj, solution-explorer, visual-studio-project

Inside a solution I'm building with Visual Studio 2019, I have a project for a console application. Inside of this project there are references to other files in different solutions, added with the:

Right click on the project → ***Add* → *Reference* → *Existing items* → *Add as link***

option. I'm afraid that using the *Remove* option (right click on the files) will also delete the original files since I know that adding a file as link will make it as if the two files were literally the same file. How can I remove these references from the project without deleting the original files from the other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you could just delete a link with delete, if it's a link it **won't** delete the original file. (right click, or press <kbd>delete</kbd> on the selected file in the solution explorer)

You could see if it's linked by it's icon:

[image]

If you really like to do it manually, then you could edit the csproj file and remove the file with the `Link` attribute, e.g. remove this line:

```xml
<Compile Include="somewhere\MyClass.cs" Link="MyClass.cs" />
```

> I'm afraid that using the Remove option (right click on the files) will also delete the original files

Sounds you need a version control system ;)